# condition variables signaling

Tags: synchronization, pthreads, condition-variable

In this link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/sync-21067.html), in the increment function, condition variable is signalled before actually incrementing the count(from zero). Should the signal be not invoked after incrementing the count? Or does the wait call in decrement_count function not return until the mutex is released in increment_function?

```
pthread_mutex_t count_lock;
pthread_cond_t count_nonzero;
unsigned count;

decrement_count()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_lock);
    while (count == 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&count_nonzero, &count_lock);
    count = count - 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
}

increment_count()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_lock);
    if (count == 0)
        pthread_cond_signal(&count_nonzero);
    count = count + 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the mutex locks, it doesn't matter if you do it before or after the signal, because the variable cannot be read until the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: So the wait call in decrement function won't return until the condition variable is signalled and mutex is unlocked in increment function?

Comment: Correct, when the cond wait is entered, it unlocks the mutex, when it wakes back up, it locks the mutex again, so because the mutex is locked in the increement function, the cond won't wake up until its unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

As [Troy says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775785/134633), signalling the condition variable before incrementing `counter` is fine, because these actions are both done with the mutex held.

However, this code does have a subtle bug if multiple threads can be waiting in `decrement_count()`.  Consider the case where two threads are suspended in `pthread_cond_wait()`, with `count == 0`.  Now, `increment_count()` is called twice in succession (perhaps by the same thread) - `count` is incremented to `2`, as it should be, but the condition variable is only signalled once.  This means that only *one* of the waiting threads is woken, and the other will wait indefinitely even though `counter` is nonzero.

This bug can be fixed in several ways:

- replace `pthread_cond_signal()` with `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in `increment_count()`; or
- unconditionally call `pthread_cond_signal()` in `increment_count()`; or
- call `pthread_cond_signal()` if `count` is nonzero after decrementing in `decrement_count()`.

In general, remember that using `pthread_cond_signal()` instead of `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is an optimisation, and you should carefully analyse whether the algorithm is still correct when using it.